# How to log the last run time in scrapy so that scrapy can scrape starting from the last run time (the URL contains the start_date field)

Tags: scrapy

I have a API where `start_date` is an input field. I want to write a crawler to run every day to get the data from the API. I want to dynamically set the `start_date` so that I won't scrape data before the last date the crawler ran.

Is there any way I can save the last run date in, for example, a log file. Then, read it and pass it into the scrapy project?

What is the typical ways to achieve this? Currently, I am thinking of using a log file.

Comment: I don’t think there’s a typical way to go about this. These seems to be many possible ways to go about this. If parsing the log file works for you, go with it.

Comment: Instead of parsing a log file, you can also write the last run date into a database, and read the value from there.